# JQuery Datatables not load immediately/disable autolaod

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using JQuery Datatables 1.10.15 I would like to search first before loading the data because i have 300,000+ rows, maybe something like

```
if (table not loaded) {
    (load the table)
}
else {
    (Search)
}
```

or any other ways, please help me

this is my code:

```
var mytable = $('#myDatatable').DataTable({
"ajax": {
    "url": '/Home/GetAllRecords',
    "type": "POST",
    "datatype": "json",
    "data": (records)
},
"columns": [
    { "data": "id", "autoWidth": true },
    { "data": "name", "autoWidth": true }
]
});

$('#btnSearch').on("click", function () {
    mytable.ajax.reload();
});
```

Comment: you might want to look at the serverSide:true option along with the deferLoading:0 option, combined, they will give you what you are looking for

Comment: @Bindrid i already tried that, it works but it messed up the pagination

Comment: What part?  Was your result set returning recordsTotal and recordsFiltered as described here https://datatables.net/manual/server-side ?